# Что нужно, чтоб title выводилось во view для каждого slug своё?

Tags: php, yii2

```
    protected function findModelBySlug($slug) {
        if (($model = Ru::find()->where(['slug' => $slug])) !== null) {
            return $model;
        } else {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException();
        }
    }

    public function actionView($slug) {

        return $this->render('view', [
                    'model' => $this->findModelBySlug($slug),
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: а где у вас в базе данных хранится title ?

Comment: да в базе где и slug в одной таблице

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В виде view

```
$this->title = $model->title;
```

Comment: как теперь этот же slug title вывести в другом контролере index динамически?